# Numpy arrays inside a pandas dataframe - how to normalize the values, keeping the original structure?

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have arrays as cells in a dataframe. The arrays are of 2 columns, a value and a category, and their lengths, meaning the amount of rows, differ.

Here's a simple example of the situation with just one column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([[1, 2,3], ['a','b','c']])
arr2 = np.array([[2, 3], ['a','b']])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, 2), columns=(['column1']))
df1.iloc[0][0]=arr1
df1.iloc[1][0]=arr2
```

Resulting df1 to be

```
0   [[1, 2, 3], [a, b, c]]
1   [[2, 3], [a, b]]
```

What I want are column-widely normalized values as new columns inside arrays arr1 and arr2, so in this case using [1,2,3,2,3], not just [1,2,3] and [2,3] separately. How can I achieve this? The structure of the dataframe df1 must not change, only what is inside the cells.

Extrating the values to a list and then normalizing them is an easy task, but how to "put them back" is where I struggle because of the complex structure. Should I add an index to all the values inside the arrays to pair them up? Sound slow and unnecessary. Could I somehow create an array of reference to the original numeric objects and replace those? But if  do, I would lose the original values... but how would I add them as a new column because I am only referencing the original objects?

I am sure there is an intuitive way of doing this but I just can't articulate it.